# Entity framework code first - work with existing empty database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Working on EF Codefirst 5.0, on deployment we created the empty database in order to create the username and permission level settings, because in the database server this user is specific to only this database.

so we done above steps and tried to run the application, it throws below exception as it was not created by the EF code first, any solutions for handling this scenario?

help on this really appreciated.

Error: 
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.